# 96 318Ti overheating help

Tags: bmw, overheating, diagnose, 318ti

So my 318 Ti has been overheating and I've been trying to diagnose it myself but haven't had any luck and first bmw I've owned so need some suggestions or some help in general

Comment: Welcome to the site. Nice car, I hope you find good answers here. Your question could use more detail as it's a bit thin. How long does it take to overheat, is it after a long drive or just a few minutes? Is it boiling over or are you seeing a light? Please click on edit and put in more information. Is there anything you've tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a Check Engine light that comes on during/near the time of the overheating? Being a 1996, your car will have OBD2.  There is a trapezoid-shaped electrical connector under the dashboard - usually near the driver's knee area.  OBD2 scanners are available that can tell you why the CEL has come on and help you narrow down the problem.  Usually auto parts stores will scan your car for free.

Comment: I've replaced the water pump and thermostat and checked the radiator hoses my fans working I haven't found out where my relay or fuse is for my water pumps since I guess my car has two and I also noticed that if I go above 3rpms that my temp goes down plus I've already done a pressure an  combustion tests and still getting no where really

Comment: I've also had an OBD2 hooked up too it and it hasn't shown any codes that I'm concerned about what else is there I could do

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Coolant level is where it's supposed to be and the coolant mixture is correct per the manufacturer's specification.
2. Be sure that there is not an air pocket in the cooling system.  Many vehicles have a "bleed screw" to purge and air in the system.  Otherwise follow the manufacturer's recommended procedure for purging the air.
3. Be sure the radiator is not clogged.  This is an older vehicle and it may have clogged over time due to age or deferred maintenance.
4. Check that the thermostat is working properly.  A stuck-closed thermostat will cause overheating.
5. Check that all the cooling lines and hoses are in good shape.  Over time these can deteriorate and sometimes the inner liner can collapse and block the flow.
6. Check that your water pump is working properly.
7. Be sure the cooling fan is working properly.